# Pandas one-hot-encode columns to dummies, including an 'other' encoding

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, dummy-variable

My ultimate goal is one-hot-encoding on a Pandas column.
In this case, I want to one-hot-encode column "b" as follows: keep apples, bananas and oranges, and encode any other fruit as "other".

Example: in the code below "grapefruit" will be re-written as "other", as would "kiwi"s and "avocado"s if they appeared in my data.

This code below works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "b": ["apple", "banana", "banana", "orange", "grapefruit"],
    "c": [True, False, True, False, True],
})
print(df)

def analyze_fruit(s):
    if s in ("apple", "banana", "orange"):
        return s
    else:
        return "other"

df['b'] = df['b'].apply(analyze_fruit)

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['b'], prefix='b')
print(df2)
```

My question: is there a shorter way to do the `analyze_fruit()` business? I tried `DataFrame.replace()` with a negative lookahead assertion without success.

Comment: `~df['b'].isin(['apple','banana','orange'])` is useful

Comment: Duplicate of the linked question. Another way is [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(..., drop=None)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) also generates dummies. Just first, munge your data to create the "other" categorical level/column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup the [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) before `get_dummies` then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) anything that does not match the set categories will become `NaN` which can be easily filled by `fillna`. Another Benefit of the categorical is ordering can be defined here as well by adding `ordered=True`:

```
df['b'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['b'],
    categories=['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'other']
).fillna('other')

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['b'], prefix='b')
```

Standard replacement with something like [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) would also work here, but typically dummies are used with Categorical data so being able to add ordering so the dummy columns appear in a set order can be helpful:

```
# import numpy as np


df['b'] = np.where(df['b'].isin(['apple', 'banana', 'orange']),
                   df['b'],
                   'other')

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['b'], prefix='b')
```

Both produce `df2`:

```
   b_apple  b_banana  b_orange  b_other
0        1         0         0        0
1        0         1         0        0
2        0         1         0        0
3        0         0         1        0
4        0         0         0        1
```

Comment: HenryEcker: yes sorry my brain sprang a leak. Yes this is correct.

Comment: By the way, if you read in column 'b' from pd.read_csv, you can directly read the fruit column 'b' as a Categorical (then each fruit will get its own categorical level. You then postprocess it to munge the forbidden fruit together into one "other" level).

Comment: Actually, [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(..., drop=None)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) also generates dummies.